# How can I set jobFinished() if I need to execute a repeated task with jobInfo?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I hope to execute a repeated task with JobScheduler.

I can't understand completely about the fun `jobFinished()` from official document.

Which code is correct between `jobFinished(parameters, false)` and `jobFinished(parameters, true)` if I hope the task can be executed repeatedly?

BTW, I have set setPeriodic(interval) for JobScheduler

**Code**

```
private fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
   logError("Start Server")

   val interval=10 *1000L

    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext, RestoreService::class.java))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()

    mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}



class RestoreService : JobService() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        logError("OnCreate")
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        logError("OnDestory")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Thread(Runnable { completeRestore(params) }).start()
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logError("OnStop")
        return false
    }


    fun completeRestore(parameters: JobParameters) {
        logError("Starting")
        jobFinished(parameters, false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters,%20boolean)):

> **You can request that the job be scheduled again by passing true as the
>   wantsReschedule parameter.** This will apply back-off policy for the
>   job; this policy can be adjusted through the setBackoffCriteria(long,
>   int) method when the job is originally scheduled. T**he job's initial
>   requirements are preserved when jobs are rescheduled, regardless of
>   backed-off policy.**

`jobFinished(parameters, true)` will re-schedule your job.

If you want to execute something periodically, then use [setPeriodic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setperiodic) in your `JobInfo.Builder`

Comment: Thanks! I have to set `setPeriodic(interval)` in my code.  Which code is correct between jobFinished(parameters, false) and jobFinished(parameters, true) if I hope the task can be executed repeatedly?

Comment: @HelloCW If you have setPeriodic() then you should `(parameters, false)` since `jobFinished()` is specific to a job.

Comment: jobFinished() won't stop the periodic time you set from continuing. It just tells the job that you are finished, to release the wakelock, so Android doesn't have to kill the job off forcefully.